# Get user id for database update - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

There is one thing I do not understand. I have a php form to update my database entries. Problem is, that I do not know how I can do it, than only a specific ID will be updated. Let me explain my problem:

I have a table with users. When I click on edit a user I will be redirected to edit.php?id=3 (for example if I want to edit the user with ID 3). Now on the edit page I make changes and click on update button. If I do that, all entries inside my database are updated. In my opinion the problem is that I have to enter inside my query something like "WHERE id = '$user_id'" but I am pretty new to PHP so I do not know what the variable $user_id should look like so that it is working.

If I do not enter the WHERE statement, than all entries will be updated. If I enter WHERE id = '$user_id' no entry will be updated. Let me show you my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Create connection credentials
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'DBNAME';
$db_user = 'DBUSER';
$db_pass = 'DBPASS';

// Create mysqli object
$connect = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

// Error Handler
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    printf ("Connection failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
}   


// Check if form is submitted
if (isset ($_POST['updatelehrer'])) {
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id']; //Updated due to a comment 
    $update_firstname_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_vorname'] );
    $update_lastname_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_nachname'] );
    $update_street_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_strasse'] );
    $update_plz_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_plz'] );
    $update_city_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_ort'] );
    $update_phonenumber_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_telefon'] );
    $update_bank_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_bank'] );
    $update_inhaber_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_inhaber'] );
    $update_iban_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_iban'] );
    $update_bic_teacher = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['lehrer_bic'] );

}


$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `teacher` SET 
     firstname='".$update_firstname_teacher."', lastname='".$update_lastname_teacher."', street='".$update_street_teacher."', plz='".$update_plz_teacher."', city='".$update_city_teacher."', phonenumber='".$update_phonenumber_teacher."', bankaccount='".$update_bank_teacher."', bankowner='".$update_inhaber_teacher."', iban='".$update_iban_teacher."', bic='".$update_bic_teacher."'  WHERE id = '$user_id'");


if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 0) //<--
{
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
} else {
   header("Location: admin.php");// send to profile overview page
   exit;
}
mysqli_close($connect); 

?>
```

Can someone tell me what I can do so that only the specific user with the specific ID will be updated? I would really appreciate everyones help.

EDIT:
I updated my code above and inserted $_POST['user_id']. Here is a part of my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="update_profile_teacher.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">ID (versteckt):</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['id']; ?>">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Passwort:</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
     <input type="password" name="lehrer_passwort" class="form-control" value="passwordonetwo">
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">E-Mail:</label>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="lehrer_email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['email']; ?>" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse">
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

EDIT 2:
Here is the code on how I get the $user_id on my edit page

```
<?php
$user_id = $_GET['id'];
$get_user = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE id = '$user_id'";
$result_get_user = mysqli_query($connect, $get_user);
$_SESSION['data'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_get_user);
?>
```

Comment: Hi there. I have noticed that you are asking alot of questions about php. Have you taken the time to do research and bug fix, yourself, before coming here?

Comment: *"I tried $user_id = $_GET['id']; but that was not working at all."* - That doesn't help us. You need to show us the method you're using for it. Where something is populated from, if from a query or an href. Edit: ok, saw it. Well, something is failing.

Comment: Hey! Yes I did. I read a lot during the last weeks and a few days ago I started my first test project. Most of my questions are specific and I cannot find any related literature for my questions. I am very thankful to all the help I get here because it helps me a lot to understand my issues and to find solutions for my specific problems.

Comment: you're also mixing MySQL functions `mysql_close($connect);` - Please remember this and for future scripts you may write or questions. There should NOT be any instances of `mysql_` anywhere in your code that involves `mysqli_`.

Comment: Start by troubleshooting/debugging. First, what is the URL you currently have when this PHP script is called?

Comment: same for `mysql_error()` - you're not getting the real error why your code may be failing. Again... `mysql_` + `mysqli_` do NOT intermix. `mysqli_error($connect)` plus you've no error reporting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for pointing that out. I changed everything from mysql to mysqli in my code! I try to avoid mixing those two things. It is still hard for me cause I have to focus on so much more :)! But mysqli_error($connect) also does not show me any error.

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii- , changing everything to `mysqli` is recommended since `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: @ChristophC. Again, First Step: What is the current URL you use to run this script? Also, how are you accessing this page? is it when you submit a form?

Comment: I think the (root) problem may lie inside your other file and that if using a form, then a hidden attribute was probably not used, or isn't populating correctly or doesn't have a name attribute. That's my take on this. If it were populating correctly, then using your present `WHERE` clause along with `$user_id = $_GET['id'];` shouldn't be failing. I doubt the problem is in what you posted here.

Comment: @ChristophC. Due to your lack of feedback I will move on to another question. If you still need help troubleshooting this I can help you remotely. Email me here if you want to connect: lokazo8@yahoo.com

Comment: I am sorry for my "lack of feedback" but I had to edit my current code thanks to your comments. I posted my current code above and added a part from my form. Will give you an answer in my next comment.

Comment: @CodeGodie YES when I submit my form on edit_profil_teacher.php I will be forwarded to update_profile_teacher.php and there I get the message "Could not update data".

Comment: What code do you exactly need? The whole form? Because I already posted the complete update_profile_teacher.php! Now you want to see the complete page where I submit the form?

Comment: what you posted as an edit, isn't enough. We need to see the query that fetches the data for it. As to how this gets set `$_SESSION['data']['id']` is unknown. The user_id variable needs to be the session array and must be set/not empty.

Comment: try `$user_id = $_SESSION['data']['id'];` and inside a conditional `if(isset())` theoretically, that should work, IF it's set/not empty.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did not try your latest comment but right now I do not get an error message anymore. BUT problem is that data are not changed inside my database. Does that help you to help me?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited my first post and added the code so you can see how I get my $_SESSION['data']['id']

Comment: your entire table is being updated because obviously, your `WHERE` clause is failing. Subsequently, you should be using a conditional statement to check if the session array is set/not empty before attempting to do the update. Otherwise, if the session array is empty, it will still update your entire table. You need to re-think this.

Comment: Look at present HTML source from your first file. Does anything appear for `<input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['id']; ?>">
  </div>`? if it is showing `value=""` then your session (array) is failing. Again, we don't know where that session is initially set and if you started the session inside all files including your form. Your question still remains unclear. You should be able to fix this, with all the comments I've given you so far and without seeing the rest of your code. Good luck. I have to move on now, it's getting too long now.

Comment: @ChristophC. Thanks for the update, but as I said, you can email me so that I can help you remotely. This is just too complex. Its pretty much debugging your code and that is hard to do in just an exchange of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is just exemplary since i do not know your html-markup or the creation of it.*

Add a hidden input field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>">
```

And in your php-code you can access the userId after the form submit with
**Do not forget to escape your data!**

`$userId = $_POST['userId'];`

Comment: Do not forget to filter incoming post/get.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` on an `int`?

Comment: @Script47: My bad, i do not use integers as ids :)

Comment: @TobiasKun well TBH I could be wrong here too, I assumed it would be an `int`. Maybe put both options?

Comment: @Script47: No you are right. The TS wrote that it is a value of ID 3.

Comment: @TobiasKun not to be ***that*** guy, but I think you mean *exemplary* or *example*.

Comment: @CodeGodie: I meant TS (Thread-Starter). I think i've crossed my weak point. Clearly should take vacation of the internet ^^

Comment: Gotcha.. never head of it. However I have heard of OP (Original Post)

Comment: @CodeGodie or *Original Poster*? :P

Comment: You are expecting int in $_POST['userId'] but it's a easy thing to send inside something completely different in that case.

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski: Where are you heading with this?

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad I understand wrongly your discussion.

Comment: This answer is good, but would only work if OP's other file is pulling in the data from their table correctly. However, that POST should be a GET. But you have `$userId` and `echo $user_id;` which will fail or might fail. Best to be consistent. OP's question to me, is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I added it to my first post here but form is still not working. I added an hidden field to my form but still not working. Something must still be wrong ... :(

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I've changed the echo. In the end it should be regardless if `$_GET` or `$_POST?  is used, when the form is posted to the same url and the input field is set. But with the last comment of the TS it seems that the population is the problem. :)

Comment: @ChristophC.: You've used `user_id` in your form and `user_ID` in your php code. These are 2 differen vars.

Comment: thanks @TobiasKun I changed that but still not working

Comment: @ChristophC.: you try to escape an integer with mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: @TobiasKun yeah you are right. I changed it again in my code above. Now form is submitted without an error but nothing is changed inside my database. Any other idea?

Comment: @ChristophC. Did you remove the single quotes  around the `$user_id` in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @TobiasKun thank you! That´s it! Now it is working! Thank you to everyone who helped me! I really appreciate that!!!!

Answer (score -1):

I see one mistake in your SQL statement, try to change this line:

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `teacher` SET 
     firstname='".$update_firstname_teacher."', lastname='".$update_lastname_teacher."', street='".$update_street_teacher."', plz='".$update_plz_teacher."', city='".$update_city_teacher."', phonenumber='".$update_phonenumber_teacher."', bankaccount='".$update_bank_teacher."', bankowner='".$update_inhaber_teacher."', iban='".$update_iban_teacher."', bic='".$update_bic_teacher."'  WHERE id = '$user_id'");
```

into this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `teacher` SET 
     firstname='".$update_firstname_teacher."', lastname='".$update_lastname_teacher."', street='".$update_street_teacher."', plz='".$update_plz_teacher."', city='".$update_city_teacher."', phonenumber='".$update_phonenumber_teacher."', bankaccount='".$update_bank_teacher."', bankowner='".$update_inhaber_teacher."', iban='".$update_iban_teacher."', bic='".$update_bic_teacher."'  WHERE id = '".$user_id."'");
```

You should see the difference between these two on WHERE part.

Comment: thank you! Tried your code but still the same issue. I get the message "Could not update data: " and nothing has changed inside the database.

Comment: same difference. `'$var'` = `'".$var."'` - not my downvote btw.

Comment: Christoph could you show us what you get after "Could not update data: "  ?

Comment: Well I would love to show you that but there is nothing. mysqli_error($connect) shows nothing. Any idea why? Btw I also did not downvote you. I appreciate every help

Comment: Try to do this step by step. If you are new in PHP it will be good for you. Create a new file, then inside connect to you db check if it's working if it is try to make a simple delete specific record from db but hardcode id in your code, next step will be to get id from $_GET and so on...